# Ошибка SSL при установке telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, ssl, pip

Решил начать разработку телеграмм бота на python3.6 . Проблема возникла при загрузке с помощью Pip. 
При вводе pip install telebot или pytelegrambotapi выходят данная ошибка:
SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
[чуть позже загружу фото]
.
Я уже искал по интернету но какого-то решения не нашёл. Как я понял, ошибка в SSL сертификате, но в каком и что делать я не знаю.

ОС: Ubuntu 16.04 (x64 , VirtualBox)

Comment: ркн не может быть к этому причастен?

Comment: если не рнк, то кто-то вместо него. попробуй использовать впн или любое другое туннелирование.

Comment: попробую впн, отпишусь об результате

Comment: Во время попыток не стоит забывать, что нужная библиотека называется pyTelegramBotApi, а не telebot

Comment: Вообщем, каким-то чудом из другого wi-fi он загрузился. Узнал у знакомого что это без проблем решается с помощью любого VPN(который коннектится к евро странам)